# how to add custom bootstrap theme in asp dotnet core 2.0 - angular projects?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am currently hovering over asp dotnet core 2.0 with angular spa project. the default bootstrap theme is ok to continue but I am thinking about using a custom theme of bootstrap. But I can't find where to change it. Can anybody please tell me where I need to carry on the edits?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a *custom theme*? Would this be an additional CSS file that overrides some of the Bootstrap styles or would it be a customised version of the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @serpent5 I am preferring customised version of bootstrap css

Comment: First install the bootstrap. Then replace the original bootstrap css file with custom css file in the "node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css" folder. Change the angular-cli.json style array and add the pathe "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",. Then run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js and webpack in command prompt. Refresh the page.

Comment: I have got the same problem today, simply just commenting all styles' sources in angular.json, and leaving only your custom bootstrap source, my one is from bootswatch: `node_modules/bootswatch/dist/darkly/bootstrap.min.css`. It works for me.

Comment: I would not replace the bootstrap original file, past you css in the style.css file in the angular project. the style is loaded after the bootstrap css so it will override the bootstrap css.